# Find frequencies of multiple strings combined and plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, frequency, analysis

I have a df that looks like

| tags | Year |
| --- | --- |
| North America , Economy - Goods , Economy - Spending - Federal | 2008 |
| Europe , Economy - Goods , Trading History & Goods | 2009 |

They are not in order and there is a space after the last word before each comma.

"North America" and "Europe" would be considered master tags, and the rest would be sub-tags.

I am trying to find the frequencies of a master tag + a sub-tag so that it would like:

| North America , Economy - Goods | Europe , Economy - Goods | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2008 |
| 0 | 1 | 2009 |

and then plot the frequencies of both columns in the same graph.

From a previous question, I used this code to find frequencies of single tags and plot them:

```
df <- data.frame(tags = c("North America , Economy - Goods , Economy - Spending - Federal", "Europe , Economy - Goods , Trading History & Goods"), Year = c(2008, 2009))

df1 <- df %>%
  separate_rows(tags, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
  separate(tags, c('tags', 'Value'), sep = '\\s*-\\s*',fill = 'right') %>%
  mutate(tags = trimws(tags)) %>% 
  count(Year, tags) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = tags, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)

# Subset for specific tags 
    df2 <- subset(df1, select = c("Year", "North America", 
    "Europe"))

# Reshape data frame for ggplot
    df3 <- data.frame(x = df2$Year,                            
                      y = c(df2$"North America", df2$"Europe"),
                      group = c(rep("North America", nrow(df2)),
                              rep("Europe", nrow(df2))))
# Plot
ggplot(df3, aes(x, y, col = group)) +            
   geom_line()
```

But I am not sure how to alter this code to do multiple tags combined.

Thank you!

EDIT:
Not sure if this helpful to anyone, but posting the solution I used that worked on my df:

```
df_1 <- df %>%
  filter(grepl("\\bNorth America\\b", tags)) %>%
  filter(grepl("Economy - Goods", tags)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>% 
tally()


df_2 <- df %>%
  filter(grepl("Europe", tags)) %>%
  filter(grepl("Economy - Goods", tags)) %>%
  group_by(Year) %>% 
    tally()


# merge table
df3 <- full_join(df_1, df_2, by = "Year")
df3[is.na(df3)] <- 0

# plot
dfm <- melt(df3, id.vars = "Year")

p <- ggplot(dfm, aes(x = Year, y = value, colour = variable))
p + geom_line() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1999, 2020), breaks = c(seq(1999,    
2020, 1))) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example? The code you are sharing is not runnable as it lacks some variables (`df`, `tages`, ...). In fact, you should consider using the `reprex` package whenever you share code on SO.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I've edited the original example to include a reproducible script. I will look into reprex as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example dataset might be too little to be very useful in our answers. Moreover, the plot that you proposed is quite odd, with Year as numeric. If my proposal is not what you are looking for, you might want to draw the plot you want by hand and post it.

Still, here is some solution to what I understood was your problem:

```r
library(tidyverse)
  
master_tags = c("North America", "Europe")
df1 = df %>%
  mutate(master_tag = str_extract(tags, master_tags)) %>% 
  separate_rows(tags, sep = ',\\s*') %>% 
  mutate(tags = str_trim(tags)) %>% 
  filter(!tags %in% master_tags)

ggplot(df1, aes(x=master_tag, fill=tags)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat="count", position="dodge") + 
  facet_wrap("Year")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Here, we can extract the master tag using `stringr::str_extract()` and remove it later when appropriate using `dplyr::filter()`. Then, we can directly count using `geom_histogram()`.

Obviously, this plot would be much more informative with a larger input dataset.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I tried to recreate it using this code, but it was not working very well. I figured out a workaround that I think works for my purposes, will add to original comment.